# Retrieve Date/User of Most Recent Update Across Multiple Tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have several tables in an Oracle database that pertain to an employee's record. Each of these tables contains three similar columns: `EMPLOYEE_ID`, `LAST_UPDATED_DT` and `LAST_UPDATED_BY`.

My goal is to project the `EMPLOYEE_ID`, `LAST_UPDATED_DT` and `LAST_UPDATED_BY` columns for the most recent update.

Here is the DDL for these columns:

```
create table EMPLOYEE
(
  EMPLOYEE_ID INT,
  NAME VARCHAR(100),
  LAST_UPDATED_BY VARCHAR(200),
  LAST_UPDATED_DT DATE
);

create table EMPLOYEE_AWARD
(
  AWARD_ID INT,
  EMPLOYEE_ID INT,
  AWARD_NAME VARCHAR(100),
  LAST_UPDATED_BY VARCHAR(200),
  LAST_UPDATED_DT DATE
);

create table EMPLOYEE_ADDRESS
(
  ADDRESS_ID INT,
  EMPLOYEE_ID INT,
  ADDRESS VARCHAR(100),
  LAST_UPDATED_BY VARCHAR(200),
  LAST_UPDATED_DT DATE
);
```

To explain further, so if a manager added an employee record to the `EMPLOYEE` table last week and one week later added an EMPLOYEE_AWARD, I want to retrieve the most recent value of `LAST_UPDATE_DT` as well as the corresponding `LAST_UPDATED_BY` value.

Simply put, I want to determine who made the latest update to an employee's record (which spans across multiple tables.

I have tried to union all of these tables together and select the `max(LAST_UPDATED_DT)`, however I cannot figure out how to get the correct value for `LAST_UPDATED_BY`.

Here is the SQL of my attempt:

```
select employee_id, max(last_updated_dt), last_updated_by from 
(
select employee_id, last_updated_dt, last_updated_by from 

EMPLOYEE
UNION
select employee_id, last_updated_dt, last_updated_by from 

EMPLOYEE_AWARD
UNION
select employee_id, last_updated_dt, last_updated_by from 

EMPLOYEE_ADDRESS
)
latest
where employee_id = 1
group by employee_id;
```

I have also created a SQL Fiddle to demonstrate my issue:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b0e2/4

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can union them together and then order the output by the last_updated_dt in descending order and just limit the output to 1.

```
SELECT employee_id,
       last_updated_dt, 
       last_updated_by
  FROM (SELECT employee_id, last_updated_dt, last_updated_by 
          FROM employee
        UNION
        SELECT employee_id, last_updated_dt, last_updated_by 
          FROM employee_award
        UNION
        SELECT employee_id, last_updated_dt, last_updated_by 
          FROM employee_address
       ) last
 WHERE employee_id = 1
 ORDER BY last_updated_dt DESC
 LIMIT 1
```

To make it more efficient you'd probably want to put the criteria in the UNION subquery.

```
SELECT employee_id,
       last_updated_dt, 
       last_updated_by
  FROM (SELECT employee_id, last_updated_dt, last_updated_by 
          FROM employee
         WHERE employee_id = 1
        UNION
        SELECT employee_id, last_updated_dt, last_updated_by 
          FROM employee_award
         WHERE employee_id = 1
        UNION
        SELECT employee_id, last_updated_dt, last_updated_by 
          FROM employee_address
         WHERE employee_id = 1
       ) last
 ORDER BY last_updated_dt DESC
 LIMIT 1
```

As correctly pointed out in the comments, the above solutions only work in MySQL, not Oracle.  Here's a version that should work in Oracle.

```
SELECT DISTINCT employee_id,
                FIRST_VALUE(last_updated_dt) OVER (ORDER BY last_updated_dt DESC), 
                FIRST_VALUE(last_updated_by) OVER (ORDER BY last_updated_dt DESC)
  FROM (SELECT employee_id, last_updated_dt, last_updated_by 
          FROM employee
         WHERE employee_id = 1
        UNION
        SELECT employee_id, last_updated_dt, last_updated_by 
          FROM employee_award
         WHERE employee_id = 1
        UNION
        SELECT employee_id, last_updated_dt, last_updated_by 
          FROM employee_address
         WHERE employee_id = 1
       )
```

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that he was using Oracle.  When I went to the SQL Fiddle example it defaulted to MySQL, so I went that route.  I think your answer is a good one.  Maybe put the criteria, **WHERE employee_id = 1** in each query in the UNION subquery.

Comment: +1 for the `FIRST_VALUE`. I'd change `UNION`to `UNION ALL` as you select the newest date anyway. And the `WHERE employee_id=` could be moved out of the innermost select, so it's written only once instead of three times...

Answer (score 3):

I have a solution, but it is butt ugly:

1. `UNION` of all employee_ids, last_updated_dt, last_updated_by
2. Sort by last_updated_dt with an analytic function
3. Filter out the latest change

.

```
SELECT employee_id, last_updated_dt, last_updated_by
  FROM (
        SELECT employee_id, last_updated_dt, last_updated_by, 
                row_number() OVER (
                  PARTITION BY employee_id 
                  ORDER BY last_updated_dt DESC) AS rn
          FROM (
                SELECT employee_id, last_updated_dt, last_updated_by 
                  FROM EMPLOYEE 
                 UNION ALL
                SELECT employee_id, last_updated_dt, last_updated_by 
                  FROM EMPLOYEE_AWARD
                 UNION ALL
                SELECT employee_id, last_updated_dt, last_updated_by 
                  FROM EMPLOYEE_ADDRESS
               )
       )
  WHERE rn=1;
```